# Double 'for' loop - only internal loop is working

Tags: excel, vba

my first post here. You guys have helped me million times, but this time I haven't managed to find the answer in google or here.

I created 2 for loops, one inside the other in Excel, shortened version here:

```
For r = 3 To 25
    For col = rota_current_col To 100
        Debug.Print "Current position:" & r & "," & col     // + some code later
    Next col
//some code
Next r
```

And first loop is not working at all. I'm not touching any of those values (r,col) in code inside loops. This debug print shows values form 3,7 to 3,100 but it's not looping to forth 'r' value.

I hope that is clear enough, thanks in advance!.

EDIT 1: Full loop as requested:

```
For r = 3 To 25 ' NOT WORKING :(

    For col = rota_current_col To 100
        Debug.Print "Current position:" & r & "," & col & " current Rota position: " & rota_current_row & "," & rota_current_col & " current Comp position: " & comp_current_row & "," & comp_current_col

        Select Case Cells(rota_current_row, rota_current_col)
        Case "U", "UZ", "U1", "UZ1"
            If Cells(rota_current_row, rota_current_col) <> Cells(comp_current_row, comp_current_col) Then
                result.Cells(current, 1) = rota.Cells(rota_current_row, 1)
                result.Cells(current, 2) = rota.Cells(rota_current_row, 2)
                result.Cells(current, 3) = rota.Cells(rota_current_row, 3)
                result.Cells(current, 4) = rota.Cells(rota_current_row, rota_current_col)
                result.Cells(current, 5) = rota.Cells(rota_current_row, rota_current_col).Address
                result.Cells(current, 6) = comp.Cells(comp_current_row, comp_current_col)
                result.Cells(current, 7) = comp.Cells(comp_current_row, comp_current_col).Address
                current = current + 1
            End If
        End Select

        rota_current_col = rota_current_col + 1
        comp_current_col = comp_current_col + 1

    Next col

rota_current_row = rota_current_row + 1
comp_current_row = comp_current_row + 1

Next r
```

Would you like me to paste full code?

Comment: You may need to include more code... unable to reproduce given the current snippet you've provided.

Comment: @Ethan, It goes to 100, Debug.Print proves it: 'Current position:3,100' . Code after it is also executed

Comment: You're not using `r` or `col` at all within the loops... why? The `rota_current_row = rota_current_row + 1` and `comp_current_row = comp_current_row + 1` are a code smell.. what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Do you have any `ON ERROR... ` statements preceding this?

Comment: yes, I'm not using 'r' or 'col' var at all and I know that's bad approach. This loop is only a part of a bigger Sub which compares values from 4 sheets with one sheet and produces another sheet for an output. I'm just curious why it's not looping.

Comment: any 'ON ERROR' statements here, no errors in this code. Rest of the code (below this) is executed with no problems. 'r' and 'col' variables are not used at all in the rest of the code.

Comment: Is there any way you can step back and explain what you're trying to do and why you need all these loops and incrementing? What is your setup, what is the expected output?

Comment: step through the code and monitor both `r` value (in Immediate Window or Local Watch Window) and what stataments are executed one after another

Comment: When you write in the inner loop 'rota_current_col = rota_current_col + 1', 'rota_current_col' will become greater than 100, so the loop won't work. Just remove the line.

Comment: @VBasic2008 - THANK YOU :) I changed inner For statement for: '        For col = (start_range.row + 2) To 100 '   and it's working ! - start_range_row is a constant value it's not changed anywhere in the code.  Thank you all a lot !!! How to close the thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the r will not go to 4 until col = 100. The inner loop needs to finish and then the outer loop starts.

try this

```
Sub yo()
r = 3
For col = rota_current_col To 100
    Debug.Print "Current position:" & r & "," & col
    r = r + 1
    If r = 26 Then Exit Sub
Next col
End Sub
```

Comment: Changed to 'Do While' - issue is the same, only first iteration is running for outer loop. r++ needs to be just before Loop statement. This whole loop is inside other Do While loop already.

Comment: Rn it's looking like: 'Dim r As Integer
    r = 3
    Do While r <= 30

        For col = rota_current_col To 100
            Debug.Print "Current position:" & r & "," & col 
        //code    
        Next col
     r = r + 1
    Loop'    And only first iteration of 'Do While' is working :(